# PHP: Get DOM attribute with encoding preserved

Tags: php, dom

I'm currently parsing some  tags in an HTML document using PHP DOM. I want to get the value of the content attribute value of the "keywords" meta tag UNCHANGED.

For an example, the string "keyword1, keyword2`&#44;` keyword2, keyword3" returns "keyword1, keyword2, keyword2, keyword3", and therefore, breaks the real amount of keywords in the output XML Document.

I have already tried using "htmlentities()", but it didn't do anything.

Comment: To be clear, is "keyword2&#44; keyword2" supposed to be a single keyword that so happens to be a repetition such as "Johnson & Johnson" or is it actually two keywords and you are trying to drop a repeated value.  Also, just so you know, most major search engines do not use the Keywords metatag anymore; so, I do not know if that effects the importance of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes. "keyword2&#44; keyword2" is a single keyword.

Comment: have you tried using explode(",",$string)?

Comment: Also, yes, I know that most Search Engines don't use it anymore. I'm using it as a alternative for some auto-generated XML.

Comment: The problem is that `$meta_tag->getAttribute("content")` returns `&#44;` as ",". So using explode won't help.

Comment: I would go for a regex in this case, but maybe DOMDocument: substituteentities  is helpful here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.substituteentities

Comment: Unfortunately substituteentities doesn't work for my case. Just tried it.

Comment: I ran a few tests and it appears browsers convert metatags from &#44; to a comma in code.  This means it it is already no longer &#44; by the time it becomes part of your DOM. you will probably need to access that upstream in your SQL query if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late, but after I revisited my code to make some edits, I found the solution via regex.

```
function GetMetaTagsContentIntact($html, $meta_name)
{
    $get_attribute_value = function($attrib, $tag)
    {
        //get attribute from html tag
        $re = '/' . preg_quote($attrib) . '=([\'"])?((?(1).+?|[^\s>]+))(?(1)\1)/is';
        if (preg_match($re, $tag, $match))
        {
          return urldecode($match[2]);
        }
        return false;
    };

    $output; // Get all meta tags.
    preg_match_all("|<meta[^>]+name=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]" . "+content=\"([^\"]*)\"?[^>]+>|i", $html, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $output = $output[0];
    // Get specified mata tag's content value.
    foreach($output as $tag)
    {
        if($meta_name == trim($get_attribute_value("name", $tag)))
        {
            return $get_attribute_value("content", $tag);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This takes the raw HTML (preferably parsed), and uses regex to get the meta tag itself, then from that, extracts the content value from the meta tag you want.

However, to append the data successfully to say, an XML document as I was, you need to use "textContent" specifically. More on that here: [PHP: DOMNode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)